# Why is event.total in XMLHttpRequest always 0, unless Content-Type is PDF?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I tried various days to make a progress bar for my download, a task which I expected to be quite trivial.

Everything seemed to to be just right, but the `event.total`-value was always 0 (or `undefined` in the angular-version.

This is basically how the file got passed:

```php
<?php // backend.php
if (isset($_GET["file"])) {
    $file = "dlstuff/{$_GET["file"]}";
}

$stream = fopen($file, 'rb');
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: text/plain", true);

fpassthru($stream);
```

And the header was exposed in `.htaccess` as [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24073356/2163226):

```
Header add Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Length"
```

I obtained the file with Javascript like this:
The application was written in angular, but I could reproduce it with simple plain HTML:

```js
  const oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

  oReq.addEventListener("progress", oEvent => {
    console.log("progress");
    console.log({ loaded: oEvent.loaded, total: oEvent.total, status: oReq.status });
    console.log(oReq.getAllResponseHeaders());
  });

  oReq.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log("complete");
    console.log({ status: oReq.status, downloaded: oReq.response.length });
    console.log(oReq.getAllResponseHeaders());
  });

  oReq.open("GET", "http://localhost/backend.php?file=whatever.htm");

  oReq.send();
```

I read a lot of stuff

- [XMLHttpRequest "total" returns 0 when fetching JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729875/xmlhttprequest-total-returns-0-when-fetching-json)
- [How can I access the Content-Length header from a cross domain Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850288/how-can-i-access-the-content-length-header-from-a-cross-domain-ajax-request/24073356#24073356)
- [Content-length and other HTTP headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728269/content-length-and-other-http-headers)
- [Content-Length header with HEAD requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854842/content-length-header-with-head-requests)

But still - no `event.total` and the `Content-Length` was not visible in the browser-console.

```
progress
(index):11 {loaded: 65536, total: 0, status: 200}
(index):12 access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length
connection: Keep-Alive
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 13 Sep 2021 15:09:22 GMT
keep-alive: timeout=5, max=99
server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

**I started to loose my mind overt this until I changed the `Content-Type`-header in the PHP-Script to `application/pdf` *by accident*. Suddenly it worked!
What it going on? The real application may have various file formats but I would like to treat them all as text from the Javascript side.**

--

Edit 1:

`application/octet-stream``instead of Pdf works as well. But the question remains: why?

Comment: Using `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` should not be necessary (any more, that question you linked to is several years old) - `Content-Length` is a CORS-safelisted response header, meaning it gets exposed by default.

Comment: Wondering if `content-encoding: gzip` has something to do with the problem perhaps? Try and disable that, and see if anything changes.

Comment: @CBroe I tried `'accept-encoding': 'identity', and 'Content-type': 'text/plain'` to deactivate `gzip` but nothing changed.