# angularjs - how i can get the content-length header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, header, content-length

i'm doing a http GET request to a url which has a xml file and i need to get the response header 'Content-Lenght' ?
Is there any way to get it? i must validate the size of the file before been abel to download it.

Here's my code

```
$http({
     method : "GET",
     url : "http://url/file.xml"
  }).then(function mySucces(data) {

    console.log(response);
    $scope.content = response.data;

  }, function myError(error) {

    console.log(error);
    $scope.content = error.statusText;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Angular Docs, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

response callback gets

> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

You can get response headers by calling `headers` function with header name, in this case `headers('Content-Type')`

```
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://b31fe90a.ngrok.io/xml/XML-Meli.xml"
}).then(function mySucces(response) {

  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.headers('content-type'); // it can be `Content-Type` not sure. but can be any header key.
  $scope.content = response.data;

}, function myError(error) {

  console.log(error);
  $scope.content = error.statusText;
});
```

Comment: it says that headers it's not a function

Comment: This doesn't work for me with the 'Content-Length' header. Your example shows 'Content-Type', but when asking for 'Content-Length' it just returns `null`. I still haven't found any way to get this to work with 'Content-Length'.

Comment: @jkjustjoshing Did you try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190998/angularjs-get-headers-in-response

Comment: Careful, CORS might not allow you to access that header even when doing it right : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24073356/1478467