# AngularJS - get headers in response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, https

I'm doing a `$http.get` request to a https service which has an XML file and it need the `headers('Content-length')` to know it size.

This's my code:

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "https://url.com/xml_file.xml"
}).then(
  function sCallback(data, status, headers, config, statusText) { 

    console.log( headers('Content-Length') );

}, function eCallback(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {

    $log.warn(data, status, headers, config, statusText);

});
```

The result of the request is: `"headers is not a function"`.
Is there another way to get it?

Comment: Are you making this up? Why would you expect that to work??

Comment: yes i'm doing it. I need that value to make a validation. This should work according to the documentation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access the Content-Length header from a cross domain Ajax request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850288/how-can-i-access-the-content-length-header-from-a-cross-domain-ajax-request)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```js
 console.log( data.headers('Content-Length'));
 console.log( data.headers('Content-type'));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, content-type esists, but content-length is absent. I see that server responds with content-length using postman. Have tried to modify transformResponse to contains single function (input) {return input;}

Comment: did you actually try this or just wrote the code to give the answer?

Comment: @FoyzulKarim:YES